# How to fix "Illegal type signature" error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I ran into the following error in Haskell:
"Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables"
How should I re-use the defined variables. Thanks in advance

```
 sum :: (Double -> Double) -> (Double -> Double) -> Int -> 
    (Double -> Double)
 sum f g n = (\x -> helper f g n x)
  where
   helper :: (Double -> Double) -> (Double -> Double) -> Int -> Double -> 
   Double
    |n == 0 = 0
    |mod n 2 == 1 = f(x) + helper f g n-1 f(x)
    |otherwise = g(x) + helper f g n-1 g(x)
```

Comment: By providing a *legal* signature :). You can remove the signature of the `helper` function, in fact right now you did not define a clause with the function body itself.

Comment: Furthermore, although not strictly necessary, I strongly suggest that you name your variabel differently than `sum`, since the `Prelude` already contains a function named `sum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually looks more like a syntactical error: you never defined a function *body* for `helper`, indeed you defined the signature of `helper`, followed by guards (the `| ...` part), but you should again state `helper f g n x = ...`.

Furthermore I don't think it is useful to define `helper` here with a variable for `f`, an `g`, since these remain fixed throughout the recursion.

You can probably define the function as:

```
sumfg :: (Double -> Double) -> (Double -> Double) -> Int -> Double -> Double
sumfg f g = helperf
    where helperf 0 _ = 0
          helperf i x = let fx = f x in fx + helperg (i-1) fx
          helperg 0 _ = 0
          helperg i x = let gx = g x in gx + helperf (i-1) gx
```

We here defined two "helper" functions `helperf` and `helperg`, `helperf` will sum up `f x` with `helperg (i-1) (f x)`, and `helperg` does the same, except that we use `g` instead of `f`. We here thus use *mutual recursion* to solve the problem.

We can however solve this problem more elegantly, by making use of [**`scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl), [**`take :: Int -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) and [**`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum):

```
sumfg :: Num a => (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> Int -> a -> a
sumfg f g n x = sum (take n (scanl (flip ($)) (f x) (cycle [g, f])))
```

Here we thus make an infinite list of `g` and `f`, like `[g, f, g, f, g, f, ...]` with `cycle [f, g]`. We then use `scanl (flip ($))` to each time apply the accumulator to one of the functions, and yield that element. We take the first `n` items of that list with `take n`, and finally we use `sum` to sum up these values.

For example:

```
Prelude> sumfg (2+) (3*) 5 1
91
```

Since `(2+1) + (3*(2+1)) + (2+(3*(2+1))) + (3*(2+(3*(2+1)))) + (2+(3*(2+(3*(2+1)))))` is `91`.

We also generalized the signature: we can now work with any numerical type `a`, with the two functions `f` and `g` of type `f, g :: a -> a`.